# Equivalent of express app.get("/:users/:names") in yaml for PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, yaml

You know how in Node.js/Express/MongoDB stacks you can do the whole

```js
app.get("/") {
  helloWorld()
}

app.get("/:users/:names") {
  script()
}
```

Is it the same idea for App Engine's app.yaml? Or am I looking at this file in a completely backwards way. This file is my routing file equivalent, right?

```js
handlers:
- url: /.*
  script: helloworld.php
  
- url: /users/names/
  script: getName.php
```

So if my app wants to grab user-253's name, it would select the user, and query for the name using the info it grabbed from this GET request?

Answer (score 0):

I use Symfony to read yaml files: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/yaml/yaml_format.html

The code looks like this:

```
$yamlFile = __DIR__ . '/Routes.yaml';
$routes = yaml::parse(file_get_contents($yamlFile));

// Get routes into an associative array and show the urls.
$handlers = $routes['handlers'];

echo 'Url: ' . $handlers[0]['url'] . "\n";
echo 'Script: ' . $handlers[0]['script'] . "\n";
echo "\n";
echo 'Url: ' . $handlers[1]['url'] . "\n";
echo 'Script: ' . $handlers[1]['script'] . "\n";

/*
Output:

Url: /.*
Script: helloworld.php

Url: /users/names/
Script: getName.php

*/
```

Note: You need to format your yaml file as below or it would throw this exception: **You cannot define a sequence item when in a mapping.**

```
handlers:
    - url: /.*
      script: helloworld.php

    - url: /users/names/
      script: getName.php
```